# Excel VBA UserForm Code Stops Running After Cell Change

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using a UserForm to fill in two cells with data selected from a list box. The list box is populated from a table on another sheet.

Currently the code will update the value in B2 and then stops executing, before B3 is edited. I can't see what is causing the code to stop at this point.

Here is the code for the UserForm, which is activated by a double click event.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Table")

User_List.List = sh.Range("A1:B10").Value
User_List.ColumnWidths = "85;135"

End Sub

Private Sub OK_Button_Click()

Range("B2").Value = User_List.List(User_List.ListIndex, 0)
Range("B3").Value = User_List.List(User_List.ListIndex, 1)

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have this code `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the sheet code module?

Comment: No - and I should have. Whoops. Thanks for pointing that out, working fine now.

Comment: I guess you have that in the Worksheet_Change Event? Do not forget to set back to True.